# Detect OS and change the path appropriately in R

Tags: linux, windows, r, path

I have two operating systems installed on my computer - windows and linux. When I write my scripts in windows and then I try to run them on linux, I have to change every path.

For example, to set my working directory in windows, I have to type `setwd("d://MyStatistics")`.

However, in linux, this command is `setwd("/media/55276F9D5951EC83/MyStatistics")`.

**Is it possible to automatically detect current operation system and change the path if it is from the other system?**

Answer (score 3):

Use an `if` condition which tests `R.version$platform` or `.Platform$OS.typ`.

```
# It's as simple as...
path <- "/media/55276F9D5951EC83/MyStatistics"
if( .Platform$OS.type == "windows" )
  path <- "d:\\MyStatistics"

setwd( path )
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is only the first part of my problem. Now I have to somehow change the path.

Comment: I don't understand. If `if` doesn't solve your problem, you need to give more details.

Comment: To be more precise, now I know how to detect OS (we have a function that returns current OS), but if my path is in windows style, I have to now automatically change it to linux style (and vice versa).

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You can use the same path separator ( `/` ) in `setwd` at both systems. Also, in your example I believe you mean \\ istead of //.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon: Yes, I understand, but with this approach, it is necessary to provide both paths (if my system is X, execute the first command and if it is Y, execute the second). It is possible to set only one path?

Comment: @Roland, sorry, I mean \\, you are right. But when I run setwd("d:\\MyStatistics") on linux, I have an error "Error in setwd("d:\\MyStatistics") : cannot change working directory".

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, your solution solves my problem, but my question is whether we could remove the duplicity, since with this approach I have to always provide both paths (windows and linux).

Comment: @MiroslavSabo how do you propose to do that. It doesn't make any sense. The *only* way I can think of is that R uses tilde expansion on the user home directory, so if you stick you `Statistics` folder in your home directory this will work on all systems AFAIK `setwd( "~/Statistics" )` Otherwise you *have* to tell the computer where the folder is located.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, maybe this question is more about operating systems. Is, for example, linux able to say that disc d on windows is equivalent to /media/55276F9D5951EC83 ?

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Sys.info.html) would be helpfull.

Sys.info() returns details of the platform R is running on

Comment: The documentation states that _This function is not implemented on all R platforms_. I'd use [.Platform {base}](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Platform.html) which returns a list with the property:

_OS.type = character string, giving the Operating System (family) of the computer. One of "unix" or "windows"._

Comment: @KemHeyndels thanks that was useful to know (GuessI should RT(F)M!)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially achieve your "one path fits all" aim easily if both systems have the same sets of folders in one place (edit: just re-read the question, and since your talking about one computer, this should be the case). You could then either set that location as the working directory at the beginning of your script, using a method like Roland's answer, or make it the default directory that R opens with by adding it to Rprofile.site in each OS. You could then just set working directories by pasting to the initial directory.

Something like:

```
#add line to Rprofile.site for both OS
setwd("/path/to/folder/containing/data/folders")
```

then in the script:

```
starting.directory = getwd() #at beginning of script
setwd(paste0(starting.directory, "/MyStatistics"))
```

You could also add "starting.directory" as an object in Rprofile.site instead:

```
#add line to Rprofile.site for both OS
starting.directory <- "/path/to/folder/containing/data/folders"
```

then use the same paste0 as above.

You could also alter Rprofile.site in both OS to contain objects with names of various working directories, which point to the same folder with OS specific paths so that they can just be referred to as "setwd(myStatsDirectory)", and pasted to as above. Maybe the best way is to do something like that for every drive you'd like to be able to use with both systems, so you could do something like:

```
setwd(D.Drive)
setwd(paste0(D.Drive, "/folder1/folder2/etc"))
```

(edit: this is a similar method to  Simon O'Hanlon's comment on Roland's answer, using tilde with the home directory)